# How can I use a custom UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a UITableView and I want some cells to be the standard UITableViewCells and I have one custom cell, called ImageTableViewCell.  I have set this custom cell in IB and have linked with its header and implementation.

The cell loads fine into my view along with the standard cells, but my data is not being put into the cell at runtime.  Here is the code I am using.  Do you notice anything wrong?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = nil;
    if (tableView == self.visitTableView && indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0){
        CellIdentifier = @"imageCell";
    }
    else{
        CellIdentifier = @"cell";
        }
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    ImageTableViewCell *imageCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (tableView == self.visitTableView)
    {
        if (indexPath.section == 0)
        {
            switch (indexPath.row) {
                case 0:
                    imageCell.patientNameLabel = [self.appointmentDictionary objectForKey:@"patient"];
                    [imageCell.patientImage setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[self.appointmentDictionary objectForKey:@"patient_small_photo_url"]] placeholderImage:nil];
                    break;
                case 1:
                    cell.textLabel.text = @"Appointment";
                    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [self.appointmentDictionary objectForKey:@"scheduled_time"];
                    break;                
                default:
                    break;
                }
        }
```

Comment: Can we assume you are using a storyboard (or registering a nib) for this cell type? Are you sure that patientNameLabel and patientImage are connected to the actual label and image view in the storyboard?

Comment: Yes, I'm using a storyboard.  I created an ImageTableViewCell class with those 2 properties and did connect them in IB.

Comment: BTW, you have a bug here where you dequeue two cells of the same type for each row. I don't think that's the immediate issue, but you should probably fix that. Are you returning the correct cell for each row?

Comment: Yes, can you help me fix that?  Also, I think the problem is, at the end of the method, I only `return cell;` and not `imageCell`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, your last comment is the problem. You dequeue two cells, and then configure the second and return the first.

To get a pointer to ImageTableViewCell, just cast the UITableViewCell pointer, like so:

```
ImageTableViewCell *imageCell = (ImageTableViewCell*)cell;
```

And also remove this:

```
 ImageTableViewCell *imageCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

And then you can go ahead and return 'cell' for either case.

Comment: Then I would recheck the connection in the storyboard.